# How to install onDemand module from an Instant App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have an android app and I want to install a new module from an Instant App. I am using the `SplitInstallManager`to do so. 
After requesting the install, I get a `SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED` with an error code = -100. According to the android documentation, the error code -100 is an internal error. (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/splitinstall/model/SplitInstallErrorCode)

This is for a modularized android app. I have multiple modules (around ten) but only one instant app enabled module and one onDemand enabled module (the one that I'm trying to install)

```
fun installAndLaunchPlayer(manager: SplitInstallManager, videoId: String) {

        var mySessionId = 0

        if (manager.installedModules.contains("player")) {
            _onPlayerInstalledSuccessful.value = videoId
            return
        }

        val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
            .addModule("player")
            .build()

        manager.registerListener(object : SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener {
            override fun onStateUpdate(state: SplitInstallSessionState) {
                if (state.status() == SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED && state.errorCode() == SplitInstallErrorCode.SERVICE_DIED) {
                    // Retry the request.
                    return
                }
                if (state.sessionId() == mySessionId) {
                    when (state.status()) {
                        SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING -> {

                        }
                        SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED -> {

                            _onPlayerInstalledSuccessful.value = videoId
                        }
                        SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED -> {
                            // HERE IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR CODE = -100
                            state.errorCode()
                            _onPlayerInstalledFailure.value = "failed to install module"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        })

        manager
            .startInstall(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener { mySessionId = it }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                _onPlayerInstalledFailure.value = it.message
            }
    }
```

I never get any other `SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED` apart from `SplitInstallSessionStatus.PENDING` that I get at the begining of the install request.
Here is the log of the error :

```
SplitInstallSessionState{sessionId=42, status=6, errorCode=-100, bytesDownloaded=0, totalBytesToDownload=0, moduleNamesNullable=[player], languagesNullable=null, resolutionIntent=null, splitFileIntents=null}
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `SplitInstallManager` to download and install a dynamic feature module like shown in [this sample app](https://github.com/android/app-bundle-samples/blob/master/InstantApps/urlless/feature/src/main/java/com/google/android/instantapps/samples/urlless/feature/MainActivity.java#L95).

For this to work the feature module you're downloading has to be marked `instant="true"` as well.

This will enable you to download the module either using the Play Core library or URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Instant Apps does not support onDemand modules at the moment. This feature is only for installable-apps.

With similar effect while as an Instant App, another instant-enabled dynamic-feature module

```
<dist:module
    dist:instant="true"
    dist:onDemand="false">
    <dist:fusing dist:include="false" />
</dist:module>
```

can also be downloaded on-demand via App Links support.

- https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/instant-app-links.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Do you mean that we can have two Instant App module ? And that we can download a second one from the already installed one ?